Separate query for items missing on first query
Looking to be able to pull a code with a separate query if it's missing from that customers list but still in the WHERE IN clause. So for this the query I have only works on items that are present in the main query when the customer is "test".
I need it to pull the next option if it doesn't find the itemcode that's listed in the WHERE IN clause from below and [item_or_pricecode] in ('ABC1234','X123456','BR23456','CX23456').
The parameters I need it to pull on for this example if it doesn't find an item code for BR23456 (which I already deleted from the data to test for this), it needs where blvl = 8 and customer is "lvlholder".
I'm not sure if I need a select around the first statement or not since my condition
WHERE p.[Customer] ='test'  
  AND p.[itemcode] IN ('ABC1234', 'X123456', 'BR23456', 'CX23456')

is only looking for the itemcode if it exists in customer "test".
Here is the code
SELECT 
    p.[itemcode],
    p.[uom],
    p.[trtype], 
    p.[alvl],
    p.[blvl],
    CASE 
        WHEN p.[alvl] > 0  
            THEN (SELECT TOP 1 x.start_date FROM pricing x 
                  WHERE x.itemcode = p.itemcode AND x.blvl = p.alvl 
                    AND customer = 'lvlholder' 
                  ORDER BY start_date DESC)
        WHEN p.[trtype] = '' 
            THEN (SELECT TOP 1 x.start_date FROM pricing x 
                  WHERE x.itemcode = p.itemcode AND x.blvl = 8 
                    AND customer = 'lvlholder' 
                  ORDER BY start_date DESC)
        ELSE p.[start_date] 
    END as start_date,
    CASE 
        WHEN p.[trtype] = 'Quot' 
            THEN p.[price]
        WHEN p.[alvl] > 0  
            THEN (SELECT TOP 1 x.price FROM pricing x 
                  WHERE x.itemcode = p.itemcode AND x.blvl = p.alvl 
                    AND customer = 'lvlholder' 
                  ORDER BY start_date DESC)
        WHEN p.[trtype] = '' 
            THEN (SELECT TOP 1 x.price FROM pricing x 
                  WHERE x.itemcode = p.itemcode AND x.blvl = 8 
                    AND customer = 'lvlholder' 
                  ORDER BY start_date DESC)
        ELSE 0
    END AS LevelResult ,
    p.price
FROM 
    pricing p
WHERE 
    p.[Customer] = 'test'  
    AND p.[itemcode] IN ('ABC1234', 'X123456', 'BR23456', 'CX23456')
ORDER BY 
    p.[start_date] DESC

Here is what I would like the final outcome to look like



itemcode
uom
price
start_date
LevelResult




ABC1234
EA
0.00
1/15/2024
29.57


X123456
CT
144.10
5/15/2024
144.10


BR23456
PC
0.00
1/1/2024
15.56


CX23456
PNL
0.00
1/1/2024
15.36



Below is the table and it's data for [sample data][1]
create table pricing(Customer,itemcode,uom,trtype,Alvl,Blvl,price,start_date)as values
 ('test','ABC1234','EA','',6,0,0.0,'5/27/2024'::date)
,('test','X123456','CT','Quot',0,0,144.1,'5/15/2024')-----------
,('test','CX23456','PNL','',0,0,0,'4/21/2024')
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,3,44.9,'07/11/23')
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,3,44.9,'11/30/2023')
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,5,41.38,'07/11/23')
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,5,41.38,'11/30/2023')
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,2,34.81,'1/15/2024')
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,5,30.49,'1/15/2024')
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,8,28.39,'1/15/2024')
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,2,49.89,'07/11/23')
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,2,49.89,'11/30/2023')
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,7,37.24,'07/11/23')
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,7,37.24,'11/30/2023')
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,4,31.43,'1/15/2024')
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,7,28.97,'1/15/2024')
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,1,62.36,'07/11/23')
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,1,62.36,'11/30/2023')
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,8,36.5,'07/11/23')
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,8,36.5,'11/30/2023')
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,1,38.65,'1/15/2024')
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,3,33.05,'1/15/2024')
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,6,29.57,'1/15/2024')------------
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,4,42.66,'07/11/23')
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,4,42.66,'11/30/2023')
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,6,40.13,'07/11/23')
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,6,40.13,'11/30/2023')
,('lvlholder','X123456','CT','',0,1,251.68,'01/01/53')
,('lvlholder','X123456','CT','',0,2,201.52,'01/01/53')
,('lvlholder','X123456','CT','',0,3,191.4,'01/01/53')
,('lvlholder','X123456','CT','',0,4,181.72,'01/01/53')
,('lvlholder','X123456','CT','',0,5,176.22,'01/01/53')
,('lvlholder','X123456','CT','',0,6,170.94,'01/01/53')
,('lvlholder','X123456','CT','',0,7,165.88,'01/01/53')
,('lvlholder','X123456','CT','',0,8,156.63,'01/01/53')
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,5,16.23,'07/05/23')
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,5,16.23,'11/30/2023')
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,8,14.82,'07/05/23')
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,8,14.82,'11/30/2023')
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,1,23.51,'07/05/23')
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,1,23.51,'11/30/2023')
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,3,17.99,'07/05/23')
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,3,17.99,'11/30/2023')
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,4,17.09,'07/05/23')
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,4,17.09,'11/30/2023')
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,3,18.89,'01/01/24')
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,4,17.94,'01/01/24')
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,5,17.04,'01/01/24')
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,6,16.54,'01/01/24')
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,7,16.04,'01/01/24')
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,8,15.56,'01/01/24')--------
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,2,19.99,'07/05/23')
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,2,19.99,'11/30/2023')
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,7,15.28,'07/05/23')
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,7,15.28,'11/30/2023')
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,1,24.69,'01/01/24')
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,2,20.99,'01/01/24')
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,6,15.75,'07/05/23')
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,6,15.75,'11/30/2023')
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,1,24.38,'01/01/24')
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,2,19.74,'07/05/23')
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,2,19.74,'11/30/2023')
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,5,16.03,'07/05/23')
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,5,16.03,'11/30/2023')
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,7,15.09,'07/05/23')
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,7,15.09,'11/30/2023')
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,2,20.73,'01/01/24')
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,3,18.66,'01/01/24')
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,4,17.72,'01/01/24')
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,5,16.83,'01/01/24')
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,6,16.33,'01/01/24')
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,7,15.84,'01/01/24')
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,8,15.36,'01/01/24')------
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,8,14.63,'07/05/23')
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,8,14.63,'11/30/2023')
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,1,23.22,'07/05/23')
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,1,23.22,'11/30/2023')
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,3,17.77,'07/05/23')
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,3,17.77,'11/30/2023')
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,4,16.88,'07/05/23')
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,4,16.88,'11/30/2023')
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,6,15.55,'07/05/23')
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,6,15.55,'11/30/2023')
;

Thanks

I've removed the conflicting tags here; please edit your question to (re)tag the actual (R)DBMS you are using. Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?

Your sample data looks like PostgreSQL, but your query looks to be SQL Server (from @BartMcEndree's earlier answer). Which DBMS are you using? Please add the appropriate tag.

Your expected result and your query don't match. You select 8 columns, but the specified result has only 5 columns... A [mcve] is expected to be consistent!

As @jarlh mentioned your expected result does not match, how did you derive the price, levelResult for BR23456 , why price is 0 ? should it be 15.56 as thats the price for latest date or do you want price to be 0 for the missing item codes ?Does LevelResult only shows the price for latest date where blvl is 8?

Since your prior question tagged SQL Server, I will assume the same here.
You cannot extract unmatched values from an IN (...) expression. You can define your selected itemcode list either as a separate source table or in a VALUES subselect that you can LEFT JOIN to your prices table.
The original code snippet:
FROM pricing P
WHERE P.Customer ='test'  
   and P.itemcode in ('ABC1234','X123456','BR23456','CX23456')

would then become something like:
FROM (
    VALUES ('ABC1234'), ('X123456'), ('BR23456'), ('CX23456')
) I(itemcode)
LEFT JOIN pricing P
    ON P.Customer = 'test'
    AND P.itemcode = I.itemcode

You could also define Customer/itemcode pairs, if that better serves your needs.
FROM (
    VALUES ('test', 'ABC1234'), ('test', 'X123456'),
           ('test', 'BR23456'), ('test', 'CX23456')
) CI(Customer, itemcode)
LEFT JOIN pricing P
    ON P.Customer = CI.Customer
    AND P.itemcode = CI.itemcode

It is then a matter of modifying the rest of the query to handle the null values resulting from an unmatched left join. References to P.itemcode would change to I.itemcode. The ISNULL() or COALESCE() functions can be used for other columns.
Applying this to my earlier OUTER APPLY-based answer (here) you would get:
DECLARE @DefaultCustomerLevel INT = 8 -- This should come from a customer table

SELECT
    I.itemcode,
    COALESCE(PLookup.uom, P.uom) AS uom,
    ISNULL(P.price, 0) AS price,
    COALESCE(PLookup.start_date, P.start_date) AS start_date,
    COALESCE(PLookup.price, P.price) AS LevelResult
FROM (
    VALUES ('ABC1234'), ('X123456'), ('BR23456'), ('CX23456')
) I(itemcode)
LEFT JOIN pricing P
    ON P.Customer = 'test'
    AND P.itemcode = I.itemcode
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM pricing P1
    WHERE ISNULL(P.trtype, '') = ''
    AND P1.customer = 'lvlholder'
    AND P1.itemcode = I.itemcode  -- Maybe
    AND P1.Blvl = COALESCE(NULLIF(P.Alvl, 0),  @DefaultCustomerLevel)
    --AND P1.start_date <= COALESCE(P.start_date, GETDATE())  -- Maybe
    ORDER BY P1.start_date DESC
) PLookup

(Side note: The ISNULL() and COALESCE() uses above are equivalent and interchangeable. I tend to use ISNULL() for substituting trivial (zero or empty string) values for null, while using COALESCE() to select from two or more non-trivial data sources. This is just a matter of style.)
Results:



itemcode
uom
price
start_date
LevelResult




ABC1234
EA
0.00
2024-01-15
29.57


X123456
CT
144.10
2024-05-15
144.10


BR23456
PC
0.00
2024-01-01
15.56


CX23456
PNL
0.00
2024-01-01
15.36



Similar modifications can be made to BartMcEndree's earlier accepted answer, but you may need to add another subselect to fill in all of the results.
See this db<>fiddle for a demo.
